# Как настроить прокрутку на сенсорном экране?

Tags: vim

Я часто использую gvim в windows 7 на компьютере с сенсорным экраном. И при
касании экрана создаётся выделение (в режиме *S*, а не *V*).

Меня не очень устраивает такое поведение по умолчанию. Мне оно кажется
бессмысленным и неинтуитивным. Возможно ли как-то настроить вертикальную
прокрутку вместо создания выделения? Вертикальная прокрутка для меня очень
важна, но было бы здорово, если есть решение, которое также работает с
горизонтальной прокруткой.

---

*К слову:* я понимаю, что ответом может быть просто **нет**. Если вы можете дать
поясняющий ответ, почему нет такой возможности, я бы и его тоже принял. (Но буду
немного разочарован).

*Это перевод вопроса [«Can I scroll in vim with my touch screen?»](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/11126/11306).*

Answer (score 1):

*Внимание: я тестировал это только в обычном vim, но не в gvim*

Этот кусочек кода позволяет мне прокручивать текст вместо выделения при
перетаскивании мышкой.

```
function! MouseScroll()
  " отметка b - текущая позиция курсора
  " отметка a - предыдущая позиция курсора
  "mark b is the current cursor position
  "mark a is the previous cursor position
  norm mb
  let currPos=line('.')
  norm `a
  let prevPos=line('.')
  if currPos>prevPos
    norm `bma
    norm ^E
  elseif currPos<prevPos
    norm `bma
    norm ^Y
  endif
endfunction

map <LeftDrag> ma<LeftMouse>:call MouseScroll()<cr>
```

а этот дополняет режим вставки.

```
imap <LeftDrag> <ESC>ma<LeftMouse>:call MouseScroll()<cr>:norm gi<cr>
```

> Примечание: `^E` и `^Y` — это не 2 символа, каждый из них представляет собой единый символьный
>   литерал

Я использую отметки чтобы проверить, активно перетаскивание или нет. Тогда
соответственно я прокручиваю либо вверх, либо вниз.

#### Пояснение

```
map <LeftDrag> ma<LeftMouse>:call MouseScroll()<cr>
```

Первое что мы делаем, когда мапим `LeftDrag`, устанавливаем отметку `a`
(это будет наша предыдущая отметка). Она содержит предыдущую позицию курсора для
сравнений с текущей позицией, чтобы знать куда прокручивать. Потом мы щёлкаем.
Это для того, чтобы получить текущую позицию мышки в буфере (дело в том, что
перетаскивания мышки обычно не перемещают мышь в новую позицию). Затем мы
вызываем функцию `MouseScroll`.

*Внутри функции*

```
norm mb
let currPos=line('.')
norm `a
let prevPos=line('.')
```

Теперь мы получаем текущую позицию курсора с помощью `norm mb`, а отметка `b`
будет содержать текущую позицию курсора.

Мы сохраняем позиции этих отметок в переменных `currPos` и `prevPos`.

Затем внутри инструкции `if-elseif` мы сравниваем `currPos` с `prevPos`. Если
текущая позиция больше предыдущей, т.е. мышка перетаскивается вниз, мы переносим
отметку `b` в отметку `a` и прокручиваем вниз с помощью `norm ^E`.  Аналогичным
образом поступаем и в другом случае, когда текущая позиция ниже предыдущей
(мышка переносится вверх), за исключением того, что прокручиваем вверх.

Вот и всё :)

#### Дополнительная настройка

Иногда из-за перетаскивания мышкой всё равно активируется визуальный режим (по крайней
мере, у меня так), но это потому что я задал `set mouse=nic`. Впрочем, это ваш
выбор, как настраивать мышку. Также можно поменять местами `^E` и `^Y` в
зависимости от ваших предпочтений.

*Это перевод ответа [«Can I scroll in vim with my touch screen?»](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11128/11306).*